# Microsoft CRM dynamics 2011: crmsvcutil Access is denied exception

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been attempting to use the command line tool **crmsvcutil** (as Administrator) to generate a data context class and DTOs for our CRM Entities.

I am getting the following exception: **Exiting program with exception: Access is denied.**

My command-line arguements are as follows:

```
crmsvcutil /url:"http://<ourdynamicscrm>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" /u:"<user Name>" /p:"<password>" /d:"<domain>"  /namespace:OurNameSpace.Xrm /serviceContextName:OurServiceContextName.Crm /o:Crm.cs
```

The user is an Administrator on the CRM box.

Has anyone had this problem and know what I am missing?

Comment: Is the user a system administrator on the windows box or an administrator of the CRM organization?

Comment: The user is an administrator of both the windows box and CRM organization

Comment: Can you connect to the web service directly (from within a browser)? It would help limit out whether it's a tool or authentication issue.

Comment: Yes. I could connect to the service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong and it was quite simple. I had left out the **Organization Name** section in the URL.

The code below generated the desired entities.

```
crmsvcutil /url:"http://<ourdynamicscrm>/<organization name>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" /u:"<user Name>" /p:"<password>" /d:"<domain>"  /namespace:OurNameSpace.Xrm /serviceContextName:OurServiceContextName.Crm /o:Crm.cs
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using claims based authentication with IFD?  If so we ran into the same problem im our environment.  There is a bug in the crmsvcutil.

Here is some information on the work around I used that worked.

[Claims-based Authentication Workaround for SDK Version 5.0.3](http://community.adxstudio.com/Default.aspx?DN=9a7499fb-4e9a-408c-8096-6d658f9509a2)